# Releasing UIViewControllers and LLVM static analysis

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, llvm

When compiling my app with LLVM, just about the only errors I get are:

```
Potential leak of an object allocated on line xxx
```

This is in response to code creating and pushing a new UIViewController onto a UINavigationController:

```
FooViewController *vc = [[FooViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FooViewController" bundle:nil];
vc.title = @"FooFoo";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

So I guess it's suggesting I put this after the last line:

```
[vc release];
```

But whenever I do that, it causes errors EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I don't see why I would release it anyway, since I want it to remain in memory, don't I? How would I get around this to make the LLVM compiler happy?

Comment: That IS a leak, show more code to see what is wrong. Or use NSZombies to find where the bad access is coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your navigation controller will retain the view controller, so there's no need for you to do so. (i.e.: The `[vc release];` line should be in there.)

As such, I'm guessing the problem with the EXC_BAD_ACCESS lies elsewhere, but it's hard to tell without some additional surrounding information.

Comment: thanks, the problem was actually because I was double-releasing a property in my dealoc